# Is there a possible way to compress already saved Image File in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

We have noticed that some of our database sizes get bigger significantly about 1 GB in just 3 months, I have checked, and it's actually the Image file that is saved in the SQL Server that makes this happen.

I've already implemented the compress function for the client-side like in VB.Net and PHP, but the older file is still there and using 30% of our storage device right now, is there a way to compress the old file using a stored procedure or function in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Unclear what you mean: You are saving image files in `varbinary(max)` and you want to compress it? Or by "image file" do you just mean the database mdf and ldf files? What is "the old file" and "the new file"? Side points: why are you using 2008 when it's out of support, and how can 1GB be 30% of your storage, do you only have a 3.3GB drive??

Comment: No such function in SQL Server. Do it on the client side. Retrieve the image, compress it and re-update to the database

Comment: the data type is "image" in the database, and yes, we want to reduce the size of the file, some of the files even has unnecessary big size like 5MB to 10MB even though it can be compressed to 200KB to 500KB with almost no loss quality, at least I can do it in the client-size but has no idea how to do it in SQL Server
we are using 2008 because that what we use from the start of the company and it already uses 30% of storage because the database has been used for many years, I just inherited the program from the predecessor.

Comment: @Squirrel this is actually my last resort, just want to ask if there is a possible way to do it. welp, time to make compress program then.

Comment: The `[image]` data type has be deprecated in SQL Server since about SQL Server 2000. Perhaps you could use this opportunity to also migrate to `[varbinary](max)` as has been [the advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql) since that time.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have any built-in methods for image compression. You'd have to select, compress and update the image blobs from an external program as suggested, or create and use SQL CLR functions/stored procedures to do the same on the server side.

Comment: You can use lossless compression with `COMPRESS` but that probably won't save you much space. Page and row compression won't work as the data is off-row